# Move to new line with enter key

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to create a javscript method that will allow moving to the next field by hitting the enter key. This mostly works fine, except that when you hit enter to click a button, it creates a new row identical to the previous one (which is normal), but then it doesn't move to the next field straight away. You need to hit tab to go to the next one.

I would really appreciate some help on this, as I cannot get it to move to the next box and go straight to it.

```js
quickAddViewModel.prototype.addItemLine = function() {
  var self = this;
  var itemLine = {
    ItemNumber: ko.observable(''),
    ItemQuantity: ko.observable(0),
    Error: ko.observable(false)
  };
  self.itemsToAdd.push(itemLine);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.nextFieldOnEnter = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(element).on('keydown', 'input, select', function(e) {
      var self = $(this),
        form = $(element),
        focusable, next;
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button,textarea').filter(':visible');
        var nextIndex = focusable.index(this) == focusable.length - 1 ? 0 : focusable.index(this) + 1;
        next = focusable.eq(nextIndex);
        next.focus();
        this.addItemLine();
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-group" data-bind="css: { 'has-error': Error() }, nextFieldOnEnter:true">
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg K000_ASAHI" data-bind="itemCodes: ItemNumber, value: ItemNumber, valueUpdate: 'input'">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="0" data-bind="numericInput: ItemQuantity, value: ItemQuantity">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" class="icon-circle-minus" data-bind="visible: $index() + 1 < $parent.itemsToAdd().length, click: function() { $parent.removeItemLine($index()) }, clickBubble: false"></button>
    <button type="button" class="icon-circle-plus" data-bind="visible: $index() + 1 == $parent.itemsToAdd().length, click: function() { $parent.addItemLine() }"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve]

Comment: Did you try to debug it? First guess would be, you listen `keydown` on `input, select` but not on `button`. Are you sure your function is really triggered? Plus, `<button>` has default behaviors, make sure they do not override/interfere yours.

Comment: Snippet gives a Uncaught ReferenceError: quickAddViewModel is not defined